# get fields in join path with criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I wanna know is there a way to do something like this in hibernate using criteriaBuilder

```
select users.first_name,orders.payable,order_item.product_title
from "order" orders
         join users on orders.user_id_fk = users.id_pk
         join order_item on orders.id_pk = order_id_fk
```

I need this specially if I have to use group by. I search and google and also read this article but have no clue how can I do this in hibernate:

- [Query Selection Other Than Entities](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/selection-other-than-entities.html)
- [querycriteria](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/hem/en-US/html/querycriteria.html)
- [hibernate-facts-multi-level-fetching](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-multi-level-fetching/)

also I code this for selecting field in first layer and it worked perfectly for selecting first layer but it need some change to work with join and select field from other table than root:

```
<R> List<R> reportEntityGroupBy(List<String> groupBy, List<String> selects, Class<T> root, Class<R> output) {
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<R> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(output);
    Root<T> rootQuery = criteriaQuery.from(root);

    if (selects == null || selects.isEmpty()) {
        selects = groupBy;
    }
    criteriaQuery.multiselect(selects.stream().map(rootQuery::get).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    criteriaQuery.groupBy(groupBy.stream().map(rootQuery::get).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

I use Hibernate 5.4.22.Final and use entityGraph for my join.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your `selects` look like, but I suppose you are using *paths* i.e. attributes separated by `.`. In that case, you have to split the paths and call `Path#get` for each attribute name.

```
List<Path> paths = selects.stream()
  .map(select -> {
    Path<?> path = rootQuery;
    for (String part : select.split("\\.")) {
      path = path.get(part);
    }
    return path;
  })
  .collect(Collectors.toList()));
criteriaQuery.multiselect(paths);
criteriaQuery.groupBy(paths);
```

Comment: thanks for answering.it's work for single level join but for more level must use Join and Path together to complete this code but your answer help me a lot.